# How can one obtain the same-spin and opposite-spin terms of the MP2 energy by integrating out the spin?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, electronic-configuration, perturbation-theory

Just as specified on the psi4 website here: https://psicode.org/psi4manual/master/dfmp2.html, the Moller-Plesset Perturbation Theory states that the second order correction to the ground state energy, $E_0^{(2)}$, is given by
$$E_0^{(2)} = \sum_{i<j}\sum_{a<b} \frac{\left|\,[ia\|jb]\,\right|^2}{\epsilon_i - \epsilon_a + \epsilon_j - \epsilon_b} = \sum_{i<j}\sum_{a<b} \frac{\left( [ia|jb] - [ib|ja]\right)\left( [ai|bj] - [bi|aj]\right)}{\epsilon_i - \epsilon_a + \epsilon_j - \epsilon_b}\, ,$$

where $[ia\|jb]$ is the antisymmetrized two-electron integral over spin-orbitals and $\epsilon$ are the different orbital energies. As far as I know, one can integrate out the spin variable, $\sigma$, of said integrals in the following way:
$$\int\int d\omega_1 d\omega_2 [ia|jb] = \int\int d\omega_1 d\omega_2 \sigma_i^*(\omega_1)\sigma_a(\omega_1)\sigma_j^*(\omega_2)\sigma_b(\omega_2) (ia|jb) = \delta_{\sigma_i,\sigma_a}\delta_{\sigma_j,\sigma_b}(ia|jb)\,,$$

thus obtaining chemist’s integrals over spatial orbitals, $(ia|jb)$. Following this path, $E_0^{(2)}$ can be divided into a same-spin, $E_{0,SS}^{(2)}$, and an opposite-spin, $E_{0,OS}^{(2)}$, terms by integrating the spin out such that
$$E_{\rm 0,\,SS}^{(2)} = \sum_{ij}\sum_{ab}\frac{(ia\mid jb)[(ia\mid jb) - (ib\mid ja)]}{\epsilon_i - \epsilon_a + \epsilon_j - \epsilon_b}\, ,\qquad
E_{\rm 0,\,OS}^{(2)} = \sum_{ij}\sum_{ab}\frac{(ia\mid jb)(ia\mid jb)}{\epsilon_i - \epsilon_a + \epsilon_j - \epsilon_b}\,.$$

By doing this, I was able to get the expresion for $E_{0,OS}^{(2)}$ without much trouble. However, when trying to perform the integration for same spins, I haven't been able to get rid of one of the terms and get the expresion I want (which has three terms only). This happens because all four orbitals have the same spin function, so every term should mantain after the integration. I haven´t been able to find ways to get these expressions without just using algebra like many demonstrations have.